# How to use FILTER to return rows if its value is different than the above row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a "friendly" view of a more complicated sheet by filtering out unnecessary data. I want one of the filter conditions to be to return a value only if that value is different than the previous row's value.

I've tried doing a filter, such as `=filter(B:B, B2 <> B1)` which obviously doesn't resolve. How do I do an offset reference so that the results are similar to as follows:

**Sample Data**

```
| Row | Category | Subcategory |
| --- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1   | Accounts | Ac1         |
| 2   | Accounts | Ac2         |
| 3   | Accounts | Ac3         |
| 4   | Accounts | Ac4         |
| 5   | Feedback | FbA         |
| 6   | Feedback | FbB         |
| 7   | Feedback | FbC         |
| 8   | Feedback | FbD         |
| 9   | Profile  | PfOne       |
| 10  | Profile  | PfTwo       |
| 11  | Profile  | PfThree     |
```

**Desired Result**

```
| Row | Category | Subcategory |
| --- | -------- | ----------- |
| 1   | Accounts | Ac1         |
| 5   | Feedback | FbA         |
| 9   | Profile  | PfOne       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach (assuming that your posted "Row" column is not actually part of your data, but that your "Category" header is, in fact, in A1):

`=ArrayFormula({A1:B1;FILTER(A2:B,A2:A<>INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROWS(A:A)-1))})`

Comment: Perfect! This was exactly what worked for me, as my data was, as you guessed, more complicated than the example I gave. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. In future posts, in the interest of clarity, rather than adding in simulated row numbers, simply give the cell reference of the first header (i.e., "The 'Category' header is in A1 and all other data shown is relative to that."). A screen shot would accomplish the same.

Comment: This is great, but it would be good to show how it works also.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
={A1:C1;FILTER(A2:C,B1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B),1)<>B2:B)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me look at array formulas. Ultimately the other answer worked better for me.

Answer (score 0):

go for:

```
=SORTN(A1:C, 9^9, 2, 2, 1)
```

[image]